# How to position labels at the base of a box plot with ggplot's geom_text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I have the following code:

```
ggplot(data = Datos_Final, aes(x = Sex, y = Punt_Total)) +
  geom_violin(aes(color=Grupo),fill=NA, alpha = 0.2, show.legend = F, linetype="dotted" )+
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(fill=Grupo, color=Grupo), alpha=0.5, show.legend = F, width=0.5)+
  geom_point(aes(color = Grupo),position = position_jitter(seed = 23, width = 0.2, height = 0), size = 5, show.legend = F, alpha=0.6)+
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun="mean", shape=15, size=5)+
  labs(y = "Rendimiento", x = "Grupo")+
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="mean", aes(label=round(..y..,2)), nudge_y = 1)+
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y..))+
  facet_grid(.~Grupo, labeller = labeller(Grupo = c("Control"="Tradicional\n (Control)", "Experimental"="Digital\n (Experimental)")))+
  theme_apa7OS()+
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16, color = "#595959"))
```

Which gives me the following graphic:

[Tradicional VS Digital](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pq22i.png)

As you can see, the values 5, 10, 6 and 8 correspond to the number of elements for each group or number of observations, what I want is that these values are placed in position 1 of the vertical axis "y", I have tried all the ways I know and it did not work.

I have tried adding the value of the position in the "y" axis in this way, with this code, but it does not work:

```
geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y.., y=1))+
```

I have also tried adding outside aes() but it doesn't work either:

```
geom_text(stat = "summary", fun="length", aes(label=..y..), y=1)+
```

When I use the position parameter, I can only move a certain number of points above or below the reference point, so that one is higher than the other, but what I want is that all values are located at the base, at point 1 of the vertical axis "y".

I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: this probably requires the use of stage, maybe `aes(y = stage(Punt_Total, after_stat = 1))`, but you will find it much easier first to summarise the data into a new data frame and then use this for simple annotation with geom_text. *Much* (!!) less headaches.

Comment: Stack's tag-recommendation system is imperfect, please check that recommended tags are appropriate. I've removed the [tag:rstudio] tag, since it is reserved for questions specific to the IDE (and not just "about the R language"). Using that tag requires justifying/confirming that the behavior of your code differs when run in Rgui (not the IDE) versus in the RStudio IDE (an uncommon occurrence, to be clear).

Comment: I have tried to do what you suggest tjebo, but the console throws error; on the other hand, I have tried to make the summary you mention in a new dataset and then use geom_text, but as I am using facets I don't know what structure the new dataset should have.

Comment: Please use dput() to provide a reproducible data set.

Comment: The structure of the new data set should be similar to the original. Include the `Grupo` column, which can indicate which facet each row should show up on as text. If you need more help, please share  a small reproducible sample of data we can work with, such as `dput(Datos_Final[1:20, ])` for the first 20 rows.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @tjebo in his comment the easiest approach would be to create a summarized dataframe containing the mean and the number of observations per `Sex` and `Groupo` which could be used in your `geom_text` layers to add the labels.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)

Datos_Final <- data.frame(
  Sex = c("Varon", "Mujer"),
  Grupo = rep(c("Control", "Experimental"), each = 2),
  Punt_Total = runif(100, 4, 16)
)

datos_label <- Datos_Final |>
  group_by(Sex, Grupo) |>
  summarise(Punt_Total = mean(Punt_Total), n = n(), .groups = "drop")

ggplot(data = Datos_Final, aes(x = Sex, y = Punt_Total)) +
  geom_violin(aes(color = Grupo), fill = NA, alpha = 0.2, show.legend = F, linetype = "dotted") +
  geom_boxplot(mapping = aes(fill = Grupo, color = Grupo), alpha = 0.5, show.legend = F, width = 0.5) +
  geom_point(aes(color = Grupo),
    position = position_jitter(seed = 23, width = 0.2, height = 0),
    size = 5, show.legend = F, alpha = 0.6
  ) +
  geom_point(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", shape = 15, size = 5) +
  labs(y = "Rendimiento", x = "Grupo") +
  geom_text(data = datos_label, aes(label = round(Punt_Total, 2)), nudge_y = 1) +
  geom_text(data = datos_label, aes(label = n, y = 1)) +
  facet_grid(. ~ Grupo,
    labeller = labeller(
      Grupo = c(
        "Control" = "Tradicional\n (Control)",
        "Experimental" = "Digital\n (Experimental)"
      )
    )
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 16, color = "#595959"))
```

[image]